# Android Fetch request hang for several minutes

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, fetch-api

An Android Expo project Fetch and Graphql requests sometimes hang for several minutes before being sent, even after APK build. When I use Graphql subscription it always stays connected to server and signals about new data without any issue, but Graphql query hangs for 2 minutes. Then I decided to test with a new created Expo app with only one fetch function.

At first launch it works very well, but when I leave the phone for 5 minutes without any interaction and then press fetch button it will hang for 2 minutes, then sends and gets response successfully, subsequent requests don't hang untill I leave for 5 minutes again. [The Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kholmatov/github.com-jkkholmatov-my-app)

```
Steps to reproduce:
1 - I created an expo app via `npx create-expo-app my-app`
2 - Added a TouchabpleOpacity button that calls fetch function
3 - Open via Expo Go
4 - Leave the phone for 5 minutes
5 - Press button
6 - Loading for ~2 minutes (if not again leave for 5 minutes)
7 - Log the response
```

The function itself:

```
const fetchJson = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " Fetch start");
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => console.log(json));
    console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " Fetch End");
    setLoading(false);
  };
```

Here is Logs:

```
LOG 12:53:17 Fetch start
LOG {"completed": false, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "userId": 1}
LOG 12:55:39 Fetch End
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za2WM.png)
I opened JSDebugger, the Network Tab shows only console.log that saying fetch start when it hangs after pressing the button, but doesn't show the request, it shows it after 2 minutes when it gets response

I tested on iPhone and it has no issue, and tested on Android via VPN and it works as expected, without VPN Android hangs for 2 minutes again. I found almost the same issue on Github, but there is not provided any solution [#2756](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2756)

Please help, I'm searching for the solution for 10 months, I tried different PCs and Android devices but it still occurs on Android